# Push document as child and update timestamp in parent document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-update

I have a document as following:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("507f191e810c19729de860ea"),
    "updateTimestamp": Date(1234567),
    "actions": [
        {
            "timestamp": Date(123456)
            "action": "FIRE"
        },
        {
            "timestamp": Date(1234567)
            "action": "HIDE"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I add a child document to the `actions` array **and** update the `updateTimestamp` field of the parent document at the same time? The idea is that I later can sort such documents on their most recent action activity, as reflected by the `updateTimestamp` field.

Comment: Does `update` not provide that functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    { _id: '[id here]'},
    {
        $set: {
            'updateTimestamp': '[timestampHere]'
        },
        $push: {
            'actions': [new record here]
        }
    }
 );
```

Comment: I knew about `$push`, but not `$set`. This does the job, thank you.